# How do I check if text can be converted to a number in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a simple AppleScript to do some text manipulation on the contents of the clipboard.  The following code works only if the text in the clipboard can be converted to a number:

```
set CB to the clipboard
set bugNum to CB as number
```

But if the text in the clipboard is not a number I get an AppleScript error: "Can’t make "foo" into type number."

How do I write an if condition that I can use to check if CB (of class text) can be converted to a number (and put the "set bugNum to CB as number" inside that)?  Or can I "catch" the error somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already read [working with errors](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html) in the Applescript guide?

Sample code:

```
set CB to the clipboard
try
    set bugNum to CB as number
on error errStr number errNum
    set bugNum to -1
end try
display dialog "Number from the clipboard: " & bugNum
```

I skipped the code the first time round since I figured the guide was pretty clear, and far more useful than anything I could write here :)

Comment: Thanks.  If you add sample code to your answer (using a try statement and error statement) I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks for (re-)inserting the sample code.  It's convenient for others to have self-contained answers.

BTW, line 4 could just be "on error" since errStr and errNum are not used.

Comment: Yes, quite right...  the sample code went through a couple of versions where it displayed the error text or checked the error number against -1700, but I settled in the end for just setting a default.  If someone grabs the code without reading the guide, then I guess they will at least see how to grab the exception details.